# What is the definition of an Native Android App?

Tags: android, android-ndk

What is the definitive definition of the term "Native Android Application"?

**Background**: I've been learning and developing Android apps with Android SDK using Java for more than two years now. I haven't found myself needing to use C/C++ lib for my projects (yet). As I'm applying to jobs and contract roles, I came across the term "Native Android Application" multiple times and I found myself unsure if I'm qualified. I've been searching the web for the exact definition, but the following definitions is confusing to me and I hope someone can clarify the term once and for all:

**Definition A:** "Native Apps" vs "Web Apps", as in a Native Android App is built using the Android SDK with Java (or now Kotlin) and a Native iOS App for is built using xCode with Objective-C or Swift

**Definition B:** Another Google search of Native Android App pointed me to the Android NDK, with a description "The Android NDK is a toolset that lets you implement parts of your app in **native** code.. " This definition is more intuitive to me, got the word native in it.

My confusion comes when I'm looking at job descriptions, when they ask for "experience in native android application development" what do they mean?

Comment: Typically A, when you see an employment ad. Rarely B, unless the job description specifically mentions the NDK. Techically speaking, both A and B would describe *native Android development*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some frameworks that can help you to develop applications for multiple platforms (iOS .. android.. ) at the same time. Apps created with those are not native. 
(Example.: an app that functions only within a webview is not native because is made maybe with html, php.. and would function in multiple platforms).

Native android app must be written 'just' for android: they are created with Java code (or now Kotlin).

With the background you showed you've been developing native apps, so i think you should not worry.

Answer (score -1):

*when they ask for "experience in native android application development" what do they mean?*

Android Native Apps = Java most of the time, but you can use 3 language to native development, Java, C++ and Kotlin.